# Returning an instance of the Iterator interface in Java?

Tags: java, object, interface, instance

So I have been using the following code:

```
HashSet group = new HashSet();
Iterator iter = group.iterator();
```

Now, can someone please explain to me how this actually compiles OK?

I thought you cannot instantiate an interface in Java. So seen as Iterator is an interface, then how is the second line of code above, where an object namned iter(of type Iterator) is being created, working OK?

Thanks guys

Comment: The assignment operator `=` is not the same as instantiation. Take a look at the source code for `HashSet#iterator()`.

Comment: You're not instantiating anything there.

Answer (score 7):

> I thought you cannot instantiate an interface in Java.

You are 100% right, you cannot do that. However, you can instantiate classes that implement the said interface, which is precisely what the `group.iterator()` method does.

The `HashSet` class defines an inner class implementing `Iterator`. Objects of this class know about the `HashSet` object which they iterate, and also provide the methods mandated by the `Iterator` interface. This is practice is commonplace in Java: it lets you hide implementation behind interfaces, forcing the users of your library program to interfaces. The results become more maintainable, because programming to interfaces results in decreased coupling.